# How to save the python script output as a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to store the python script output as a variable

My script output has the following data on the screen.

```
python3 office1.py SUCCESS!! Success: 
{"ok":true,"id":"3afe26a36a329b1a8b98fcc805fd77c9","rev":"1-e2e221dbda9918f8e1adfef00c680383"}
```

The id & rev are basically showing the id and revison values of the cloudant db output.

I would like to store it as variable and then use hem in the next json file.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you,

Comment: write this into some output file

Comment: python3 office1.py >> output.txt

Comment: The Values id and rev needs to be stored as a variable (id, rev) and not saved to another file....